# Configuration file reading. Best practice

Tags: .net, api, configuration

Application stores configuration data in custom section of configuration file. This information is used all over the application.

Nowadays I use helper static class to to provide access like this (some code omitted or simplified):

```
[XmlRoot("webSiteSection")]
public class WebSiteConfig : IConfigurationSectionHandler
{

    public static WebSiteConfig Current
    {
         get
         {          
             if (_current == null)
                _current = (WebSiteConfig) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("webSiteSection");

            return _current;
     }  
    }

    [XmlElement("section1")]
    public Section1 Section1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("section2")]
    public Section2 Section2 { get; set; }

    ...

    public object Create(object parent, object configContext, XmlNode section)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WebSiteConfig));
        return serializer.Deserialize(new XmlNodeReader(section));
    }
}
```

Then I use it like this

```
<%: WebSiteConfig.Current.Section1.Value1  %>
<%: WebSiteConfig.Current.Section1.Value2  %>
```

What do you think of it? I find it usable because it keeps code simple, but also confused as IConfigurationSectionHandler is deprecated since .NET Framework 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in principal, i see nothing wrong with the concept.

A more manageable implementation may be to implement a default static instance accessor in your configuration section and use that.

Comment: Sorry, I already have static instance accessor (Current). Is that what you have mentioned?

Comment: @Andrew - so you do. I am off my game tonight missing the obvious. Ok, so Yeah, I don't see anything wrong with the way you are doing it, I do the same thing with my ConfigurationSections.

Comment: Ok. What do you think of custom configuration section classes that is suggested by Franci Penov?

Comment: @Andrew - I prefer to construct my configuration systems using the base classes as Franci says. But if your config works for you, I see nothing wrong with it. But.... There will come a time when you need to write another one and before that time comes I highly recommend that you read http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx (part 1 of an amazing 3 part series).  You will fall in love with the abstract configuration classes.

Comment: Oh yes, they are very flexible & I'll take them in mind. 
But probably I'll live with my configuration classes.  

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

[Create your own `configuration section`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) class.

Comment: Hmm, interesting :)  I'll try to refactor

Comment: Well, finally i decided not to refactor as I'll have to implement so many properties. Benefits of validation are not so remarkable compared to autoproperties in approach I use these days.

Comment: That is your choice to make. However, the IConfigurationSectionHandler is deprecated as you noted yourself and might be removed in future versions of the .Net framework. I agree that worrying now about something that might break in a year might seem a bit excessive, but if you start using this pattern as implemented above quite a lot, you will end up at a state where you will have to change it eventually. Might as well do it now.